# Warning Message: Column 'labels' is of unsupported type function

Tags: r, shiny

I have this list column called "labels" that i'm unlisting to get a readable data frame. Everything is working well locally but when i run this on AWS shiny server it's throwing me this error below. I can share additional code snippets but wanted to get pointers on this error first, what could this be?

Warning: Error in mutate_impl: Column `labels` is of unsupported type function

```
Stack trace (innermost first):
    110: <Anonymous>
    109: stop
    108: filtered
    107: as.data.frame
    106: eval
    105: eval
    104: %>%
    103: <reactive:filtered_closed> [/srv/shiny-server/support-dashboard/server.R#74]
     92: filtered_closed
     91: tagList
     90: tag
     89: tags$h3
     88: h3
     87: tag
     86: tags$div
     85: div
     84: tag
     83: tags$div
     82: div
     81: valueBox
     80: vbox_fun [/srv/shiny-server/support-dashboard/server.R#179]
     79: shiny::renderUI
     78: func
     77: origRenderFunc
     76: output$vb_ratio
      1: runApp
```

My Session info on server:

```
    R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3
```

Update: Additional Information: 
Loading the dataset from a global.R

```
issues <- readRDS("/srv/shiny-server/support-dashboard/issues.rds")
```

Server.R snippet below. Note: issues is the df. labels is the list.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    filtered <- reactive({
        unnest(issues, labels) %>% # remove lists from labels. 
            rename(pr_key = pull_request.url, 
                   reported_by = user.login, 
                   associate = assignee.login, 
                   release = milestone.title) %>%
            select(-ends_with("url"), -starts_with("user"), 
                   -starts_with("assignee"), -starts_with("milestone"), 
                   -title) %>%
            filter(str_detect(name, "help wanted")) %>%
            mutate(created_at = ymd(as.Date(created_at)), 
                   closed_at = ymd(as.Date(closed_at))) 
    })

    filtered_by_date <- reactive({
        filtered() %>%
            group_by(created_at) %>%
            filter(
                # created_at in df replacement in reactive. 
                created_at >= input$dateRange[1],
                created_at <= input$dateRange[2]
            ) %>%
            summarise(n = n()) %>%
            rename(created_date = created_at) %>%
            rename(issues_count = n)
    })
```

Additional Packages Info:

```
Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    box

Loading required package: methods
── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.2.1 ──
✔ ggplot2 2.2.1     ✔ purrr   0.2.4
✔ tibble  1.4.2     ✔ dplyr   0.7.4
✔ tidyr   0.8.0     ✔ stringr 1.2.0
✔ readr   1.1.1     ✔ forcats 0.2.0
── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
Highcharts (www.highcharts.com) is a Highsoft software product which is
not free for commercial and Governmental use

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    date

[1] "/srv/shiny-server/support-dashboard"
# A tibble: 3,387 x 89
```

Comment: Hi ngamita, could you share a bit of the code that causes this error? That would really help. I suspect you have an object or column name called 'label', and that it causes issues with [this function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/labels).

Comment: @Florian i've added addtional server.R snippet. Hope this guides better.

Comment: Is your AWS workspace same as local? Same R and package versions?

Comment: @zx8754 i'm not sure how's the best way to do this manually and i know this brings us to going the docker way of things when deploying. Leaving that aside run both environment scripts manually and monitored below the details which were very similar on versions and yes the R version is same too. 

Loading required package: methods
── Attaching packages